# Limit of an integral

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am trying to compute the following limit, 
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^1 \left| \frac{\sin(kx)}{x}\right|  dx
$$
After some numerical calculations, it loos like the limit is $\infty$. To prove it, I tried to use Riemann sums but such approach is not working.

Any hints on how one should prove this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that this integral approximates $\int_0^1{\frac{1}{x}} dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing variables ($y=kx$) this is
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^k\frac{|\sin y|}{y}\,dy
=\int_0^\infty\frac{|\sin y|}{y}\,dy.$$
This improper integral is well-known to diverge. For instance
$$\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin y|}{y}\,dy
\ge\frac{1}{n\pi}\int_0^\pi\sin y\,dy=\frac{2}{n\pi}.$$
Adding these up, and considering the behaviour of the harmonic
series shows the integral diverges.

Comment: How do you get the inequality ?

Comment: $1/y\ge1/(n\pi)$ on that interval.

Comment: Right ! Thanks again !